# How to extract elevation information from contour lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, elevation, contour

I'm working with OS windows 7 and using ArcGIS 10.2 and I have a point shape, which I must extract elevation for every point in it but the only useful data is a contour line shape. Not sure if it's useful but I need your help once again to lead me on how do I extract the data I need from it.

Comment: What does your attribute table contain, for both the line and point shapefile? Could you add a screenshot? I also don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Could you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have spatial or 3D analyst, you can interpolate between your contour lines, using topo to raster or TIN (TIN is only available with 3D analyst). Then you run "extract value to point".

If you don't, I recommend you to try with another software (e.g. QGIS, GRASS...), but if you need a quick and dirty solution you can use spatial join to extract the elevation of the line that is closest to your point.

Comment: @edixon gutierrez - please mark as the answer

Comment: Just one more question, but not sure if it can be solved here or in another different question. I made a DEM from those contourlines but is missplaced, so, ¿ How do I reproject a DEM? @radouxju

Comment: it should not be misplaced if your lines are in the same coordiante system as your point. Otherwise there are tools in ArcGIS for reprojecting (Project raster, data management tools, check the datum transform if needed). If this doesn't help please ask another question with an image of your DEM to show how it is misplaced.

Comment: Open a different question - or better do some research yourself, this is a common operation/